# Tera termマクロで複数の踏み台からログアウトしたい

Tags: teraterm

テラタームマクロで複数の踏み台サーバからログアウトしたいのですが、処理をループにして抜けることは可能でしょうか？
（サーバによって踏み台の数が
違うので、書き分けが煩雑になっています）

イメージとしては
wait '#', '$'

do while result=1
sendln 'logout'
loop

というように、テラタームのウィンドウが閉じるまでlogoutを送り続けたいです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wait 中に接続が終了すると、result が 0 になります。
以下のようにプロンプト等を wait し、result が 0 になるまで繰り返せばいいと思います。

```
do
    flushrecv
    sendln "logout"
    wait "%" "$"
loop while result > 0
```

Comment: きれいに閉じました！ありがとうございます